# How to get path of windows system folders?

Tags: java, windows, path, filesystems

I have a problem with getting a path to system folders like `"My Computer"` , `"Library"`, `"Home group"` etc with java.

[image: Application]

The problem is that a path to these files is like `::{xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx}` instead of a simple path `C://users` ... To get the path I use`filename.getPath()`.
How can I get a normal path to these files so I can work with them like with other files?

Comment: Many of those folders don't *have* normal paths.  They're part of the shell namespace.  They're not part of the file system.

Comment: i ve noticed that already xD. the question is how can i use them inside my programm without getting null pointer exeption

Comment: Its unclear what you actually want; You cannot use a file API to access *My Computer* and *Home Group* as they are not physical folders - they are abstractions of the shell namespace that are overlaid on-top of explorer views.  For special folders that do exist on disk you would need JNI, the Windows API & SHGetKnownFolderPath().

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add a folder to your class path. Where you can add files ,images etc.

Comment: I am trying to make some kind of a file manager with a specific functions. see the screen attached. i need to acess all folders not just one